# Why, does my code always do nothing the first time I click the button?

Tags: vb.net

My program is a WIP RPG battle game, where the user has to battle monsters to progress. I want to make it so each time the player uses their melee attack, the attack amount is randomized. However each time I load the program, the first time the player presses the button to trigger the attack, no attack occurs, even though other things are supposed to happen when the button is clicked. Such as other buttons becoming disabled.

This is the stub for the button. If necessary I can post the full code.

```
Public Sub btnMeleeAttack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMeleeAttack.Click
    tmrRoundCount.Start()
    tmrTurn.Start()
    btnMeleeAttack.Enabled = False
    btnRangedAttack.Enabled = False
    btnDefend.Enabled = False
    btnUseItem.Enabled = False
    If intRoundCountTicks = 0 Then
        dblEnemyHealthOld = dblEnemyHealthMax
    End If
    dblEnemyHealth = dblEnemyHealth - (dblMelee / dblEnemyDefense)
    lblEnemyStats.Text = dblEnemyHealth & "/" & dblEnemyHealthMax & " HP" & vbCrLf & dblEnemyDefense & " DEF" & vbCrLf & dblEnemyAttack & " ATK"
    Randomize()
    dblRandomAttackVar = CInt(Int((9 - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1))
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 1 Then
        dblMelee = 3
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 2 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 3.25
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 3 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 3.5
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 4 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 3.75
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 5 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 4
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 6 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 4.25
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 7 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 4.5
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 8 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 4.75
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 9 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 5
    End If
    If intMeleeAttackCount = 0 Then
        dblMelee = 4.5
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: put breakpoints and debug, you will see what condition hasn't been met.

Comment: Not an answer, but something I noticed. It's possible for dblRandomAttackVar to = 10. But you don't have a case for it. Plus, your numerous If statements can be simplified: `If intMeleeAttackCount = 0 Then dblMelee = 4.5 Else dblMelee = 2.75 + dblRandomAttackVar * 0.25`

Comment: Make sure `dblEnemyDefense` is initialized to something other than 0 else you will divide by 0

Comment: What is the code that actually performs the attack?

Comment: are the buttons becoming disabled or not?

Comment: @djv this is not true for the version I'm currently looking at. 0 <= Rnd() <1 so this cannot be 10 and cannot be 0 either.

Comment: @themightylc it can. Simulate with .99 from Rnd, and see what Cint does

Comment: @dvj ist does. But the code I'm looking at (as unreadable as it may be) has a `Int()` inside of the `CInt()` which truncates the floating point decimals afaik. The CInt() was probably proposed by VS, as `Int()` preserves the type of it's argument.

Comment: @themightylc you're right, the Int truncates. I didn't know that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the full code, this might be a guess but I think your conditions are the reason of this problem:

```
If dblRandomAttackVar = 2 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
    dblMelee = 3.25
End If
```

I suppose that, for the first attack, `intMeleeAttackCount` actually is 0. This means that, unless the first attack has a roll 1, the attack will never be executed, as `intMeleeAttackCount`  doesn't fit the condition.

---

Unrelated: you can pretify your code like this:

```
If dblRandomAttackVar = 1 Then
    dblMelee = 3
ElseIf dblRandomAttackVar = 2 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
    dblMelee = 3.25
ElseIf dblRandomAttackVar = 3 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
    dblMelee = 3.5
'...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I am fiddling a bit with your code to help you on your way but let's try this one here first:

**Answer**

You say "no attack occurs". Is the only feedback you get the status message in lblEnemyStats?

Then you should update that *after* your calculations and not before.

```
Public Sub btnMeleeAttack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMeleeAttack.Click
    tmrRoundCount.Start()
    tmrTurn.Start()
    btnMeleeAttack.Enabled = False
    btnRangedAttack.Enabled = False
    btnDefend.Enabled = False
    btnUseItem.Enabled = False
    If intRoundCountTicks = 0 Then
        dblEnemyHealthOld = dblEnemyHealthMax
    End If
    dblEnemyHealth = dblEnemyHealth - (dblMelee / dblEnemyDefense)
    Randomize()
    dblRandomAttackVar = CInt(Int((9 - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1))
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 1 Then
        dblMelee = 3
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 2 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 3.25
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 3 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 3.5
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 4 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 3.75
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 5 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 4
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 6 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 4.25
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 7 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 4.5
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 8 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 4.75
    End If
    If dblRandomAttackVar = 9 And intMeleeAttackCount <> 0 Then
        dblMelee = 5
    End If
    If intMeleeAttackCount = 0 Then
        dblMelee = 4.5
    End If
    lblEnemyStats.Text = dblEnemyHealth & "/" & dblEnemyHealthMax & " HP" & vbCrLf & dblEnemyDefense & " DEF" & vbCrLf & dblEnemyAttack & " ATK"

End Sub
```

**To clarify**

I think your code does what it is supposed to do, but yout UI get's updated too late. Let's say each Button is a "Tick" on the timeline of the game. Then it's

0 -> Click -> 1 -> Click -> 2 -> Click -> 3 and so on.
That is the current state of your "round". But the User Interface lag's behind, so your Interpretation of whatever is displayed will be wrong, too because what you SEE is not what you HAVE - your Question proves that - you thought the button did nothing and then started working, which is "mysterious" and will lead to an avalanche of mistakes.

Game: 0->1->2->3->4->Monster dead?!?
UI:   0->0->1->2->3->Monster not dead yet?!?

**Bonus**

This might make things easier to debug. Use comments, they are your best friend in this state of learning to program.
I do however not claim to understand more than half of your code.

```
Private Sub toggleFightButtons(onOff As Boolean)
    btnMeleeAttack.Enabled = onOff
    btnRangedAttack.Enabled = onOff
    btnDefend.Enabled = onOff
    btnUseItem.Enabled = onOff
End Sub

Private Sub showStats()
    Dim stats As String = String.Format("{0}/{1} HP {2} DEF {3} ATK", dblEnemyHealth, dblEnemyHealthMax, dblEnemyDefense, dblEnemyAttack)
    lblEnemyStats.Text = stats
End Sub

Public Sub btnMeleeAttack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMeleeAttack.Click

    'Suspend interaction with the game 
    tmrRoundCount.Start()
    tmrTurn.Start()

    '????
    If intRoundCountTicks = 0 Then
        dblEnemyHealthOld = dblEnemyHealthMax
    End If

    'Introduce a little bit of RNG
    dblEnemyHealth = dblEnemyHealth - (dblMelee / dblEnemyDefense)
    Randomize()
    dblRandomAttackVar = CInt(Int(9 * Rnd() + 1))

    'Calculate the result
    If intMeleeAttackCount = 0 Then
        dblMelee = 4.5
    Else
        dblMelee = 3 + (0.25 * (dblRandomAttackVar - 1))
    End If

    'Update UI to show what it is we did
    showStats()

End Sub
```

This does the same as your code and could still be simplified more.

Comment: @Skaibae If this helped solve your problem, please accept as answer.